# GetPivotData with a filter

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot

I want to use several GetPivotData functions, retrieving data from the same Pivot table. I want each of them to retrieve different data based on a filter value.

For instance:

Get Pivot Data for Month:January
Get Pivot Data for Month:February

Where Month is a filter on the Pivot. Is this possible using a formula?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will solve your problem. Try this workaround from Microsoft:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/287736/getpivotdata-formula-is-automatically-created-when-you-try-to-create-s

When you change the month, the value changes too. But make sure that there are no hidden items (because if not, you won't get an accurate #/data).

Comment: If this workaround is from Microsoft, please add some reference.

Comment: I updated my comment. Thanks for reminding me <newbie here/> * :)

Answer (score 0):

see the screenshot below where the `Month` to choose is based on a cell reference as an argument in the `GETPIVOTDATA` formula:

[image]

Comment: But here Month is chosen as a visible value. I need to access those values with Month as a filter, not a value. 

For instance, where Month is the filter, I want to retrieve data for "Jan and Feb" ticked. Using your data as reference, that would mean I want to retrieve "12", because that is the sum of values when Jan and Feb are ticked positive.

Comment: @ViktorZafirovski - please place a screenshot sample of what you want to do in your original question. it will help me (and others) understand more easily what you are after. thanks.

Comment: Done. I want to retrieve data from the Pivot as if the filters are set as they are in the image. But in another cell I'd like February and March, and then in another maybe January and March, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Victor,
The Pivot tables won't work like you intend to. All data that your formula shall retrieve must be visible at the same time. I suggest that you arrange for some space on your worksheet and apply the solution proposed by Scott.

NB: If you want to deal with data added month by month, for example, there is an Pivot table option to automatically add new values to the filter. Then in your formula you can use IFERROR to show blank cells when there is still no data available.

Regards,
+Daniel+